# Efficient feature reduction in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big data set of about 200K samples. each sample has a set of features (about 10) from a variety of about 100K possible features, and a few float-type measurements with it.

For example, for the given data set

```
Features                  trial             observations
{1, 40020, 8222}          4                 2
{1, 40020, 22, 16000}     14                8
{1, 20, 22, 1000}         1                 0
{42, 22, 16000}           2                 1
```

So I need a function f such that:

```
f(data, {1, 40020})=

Features                  trial             observations
{1, 40020}                18                10
{1}                       1                 0
{}                        2                 1

f(data, {22, 40020})=

Features                  trial             observations
{40020}                   4                 2
{40020, 22}               14                8
{22}                      3                 1
```

So, the function f groups the data by intersecting the feature column with a give set and summing the aggregated columns.

Consider that I need to call "f" for the same dataset with many different feature sets as the second argument, so any pre-processing that can be done once to speed up each call will probably be beneficial.

The fastest way I found is

`pandas.DataFrame([sample.data for sample in samples], index = [sample.features for sample in samples]).groupby(lambda x: x & test_features, sort = False).sum()`

But the performance was not good enough. I am guessing that this is because I am using a function for the groupby. is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: pls post a more complete example of what you are doing, as well as the pandas version.

Comment: I changed the example to be more explicit, please tell me if it's clear now.

Comment: try selecting before you group, something like this: ``df.loc[:,df['features'].isin(set_of_features)].groupby(df['Features']).sum()``; should be much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to prepare your grouping data with `frozenset` instead of `set`, as `frozenset` is hashable.

First convert `Features` column from a `set` to a `frozenset`:

```
df['Features'] = df['Features'].apply(frozenset)
```

Then this give the intersection you need to group your data:

```
df['Features'] & frozenset({1, 40020})
Out[64]: 
0    (1, 40020)
1    (1, 40020)
2           (1)
3            ()
```

Eventually you get your dataframe result:

```
df.groupby(df['Features'] & frozenset({1, 40020}), sort=False).sum()
Out[65]: 
            trial  observations
Features                       
(1, 40020)     18            10
(1)             1             0
()              2             1
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually a nice performance improvement. I wonder if there is any way to speed up the process even more by doing any king pre-processing on the table.

Comment: If the length of union of all sets is small, you can create a boolean column per value and use those columns to filter

Comment: Since the total number of elements in the sets is about 100K, this method didn't work for me. I was hoping that maybe there is a more sparse implementation for this.